# Visual Studio Team Services build server in Azure

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-devops, vstest

I am trying to create a custom build server for Visual Studio Team Services in Azure. I have installed the build agent and Visual Studio Express on a virtual machine which is running and connected to my project on visualstudio.com as a build agent in the "Default" pool.

However when I tried to run a build I got the following error:

```
No agent found in pool 1 which satisfies the specified demands:
msbuild
visualstudio
vstest
Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.98.1
```

MSBuild was already in the list of capabilities on visualstudio.com but not the other two, so I dug through `C:\Program Files (x86)` and added these two capabilities to the list:

```
vstest: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
visualstudio: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
```

The build then runs at least but I get another error during the "Test Assemblies" step. I think the most important part of the error message is `Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe`, here it is in full anyway:

```
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeVSTestCmdlet.GetVsTestLocation()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeVSTestCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.PowerShellHandler.Execute(ITaskContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 timeoutInMinutes)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.RunTask(ITaskContext context, TaskWrapper task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

I have looked and `vstest.console.exe` is located in the `vstest` folder I specified above, I've also tried adding this folder to the system `PATH` but that makes no difference.

How can I set up a working build agent in Azure?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have installed? One prior to VS 2015? Or have you installed the Community Edition of 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Express doesn't have the testing tools. Install Visual Studio Community (assuming you qualify for Community based on the licensing terms), or a Visual Studio edition (professional/enterprise) for which you or your organization is licensed.

Answer (score 1):

In TFS Build Logs under Test Assemblies I see the error:

> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe

I had VSTest set as Visual Studio 2015, I'm using VS/TFS2017 so switching to Latest solved the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to install Visual Studio on your build server.  At that point, the build agent will recognize the capabilities available like `msbuild, visualstudio, and vstest`.

Answer (score 0):

[I found a solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/415#issuecomment-147513938), you just have to convince your build machine that it does actually have VS installed. From the link:

> What worked for me was to create the following registry key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
>
> and within that key, create a new value of type string with name
>   ShellFolder and value C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0.
>
> Hope it helps